# textview.selectedRange.location in UITextview show 2147483647

Tags: ipad, keyboard, location, uitextview

i have a textview and i want to get the selectedRange.location value from that textview.
in the first time when the keyboard appear, the location value always show an integer point such as 110, or others. But if i dissappear the keyboard and then appear the keyboard again, the location value always show 2147483647. What is this 2147483647 mean and how to get the real location value?

This is my code in the keyboard will appear method :

```
    -(void)keyboardWillAppear:(NSNotification *)notification {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] 
                               objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]]; 
CGRect keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame = [[[notification userInfo] 
                                          objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey ] CGRectValue];
CGRect keyboardEndingFrame = 
[self.view convertRect:keyboardEndingUncorrectedFrame 
              fromView:nil];

[UIView commitAnimations];
NSRange selectedRange = textview.selectedRange; 
NSLog(@"selected Range location : %f", selectedRange.location);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be [`NSNotFound`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW3), presumably indicating that there's no current selection.

Comment: but i have clicked on the textview, why the location is not selected?

Comment: i still dont understand why i can't get the location in keyboardwillappear, but then i can get the value from textView: shouldChangeTextInRange: replacementText: method, so i choose to use that value...thank you Otto :)

Answer (score 1):

The number is the maximum length of an unsigned 32 bit integer, and shows up across platforms and languages.  You might see the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647).  It is the result of an overflow, a constant representing "nothing selected", or, sometimes uninitialized memory.